# passing parameters from models

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have this model where I upload a file and save it to s3 . Here is the model.

```
class ExcelFiles(models.Model):
    PLAN_CHOICES = (
        ('x1', 'x1'),
        ('x2', 'x2'),
        ('x3', 'x3')
    )
    company =models.CharField(max_length=80)
    plan_type=models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=PLAN_CHOICES,default='BASE')
    excelFile = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to=excel_directory_path)
```

and here is the code for excel_diectory_path

```
def excel_directory_path(instance, filename):
    print("instnace", instance)
    present_date = date.today()
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace();
    return 'company_excel_sheets/{}-{}-{}/'.format(present_date.year, present_date.month, present_date.day, filename)
```

What i basically wanted is to store my files company_excel_sheets/company/plan_type/time
so that no files get overwritten while saving in s3 .

Comment: so you actually want something like this: `return f'company_excel_sheets/{instance.company}/{instance.plan_type}/{date.today()}` or `return 'company_excel_sheets/{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.company, instance.plan_type, date.today())` if you don't want to use f-strings or your python version is older than 3.6?

Comment: is you didn't forget the last for filename{}  return 'company_excel_sheets/{}-{}-{}/{} '.format(present_date.year, present_date.month, present_date.day, filename)